Auto Suppression + Custom Subscription Center
We use Auto Suppressions to store Unsubscribed email addresses after we've deleted their subscriberkey from our Contacts (due to contact allotment limitations), but are looking for a solution if a customer comes back and re subscribes to our marketing emails via the Subscription Center to be able to delete them from any Auto Suppressions so that they can start receiving marketing emails again.
Is there a way to do this either via a Custom Subscription Center or another method?

This really depends on your system of record and data model for consents.
That said, you can use this approach for removing them from the list programmatically (using SSJS): Remove subscribers from Auto Suppression List
In a perfect world, you would want to do this in real time, the second someone re-subscribes. Alternatively you could query your master contact data extension (assuming this only holds opted in contacts), and identify if any of these should exist in auto suppression list (which technically is a data extension and can be easily queried). See an example here: searching contacts in Auto-Suppression Lists
I am however wondering why you, in first place, hold these email addresses in auto suppression list. When they are deleted, they will not be emailed to. And they should only be reintroduced if they re-subscribe.

I'll check out those links - thank you. We have them in an Auto Suppression because they could still repurchase again but by just because the purchase again does not mean the are opting back into marketing emails after unsubscribing.

@HaileeMarcinek I agree that purchasing should not add them to the commercial audience. But this should be resolved with your data model, as a purchase should not set their opt-in flag in whatever system you are using for consent management.

When they purchase they are sent Order/Shipping confirmation emails and once they are sent through the system they get added to All Subscribes and since SFMC reads them as a new subscriber they are set with an 'Active' Status. How would you suggest we prevent that from happening?

@HaileeMarcinek I wrongly assumed you used something more sophisticated than All Subscribers list for consent management. Normally I would either be using a different CRM/CIAM application for consent management, alternatively a set of data extensions, e.g. like described in this article/video. You are correct, in case you only use All Subs, just sending a transactional email will opt them in, which is far from optimal...
